# How to generate a navmesh from a set of 3D meshes from scratch

Tags: path-finding, navmesh

I've found a great article on how to build a [constrained delaunay triangulation](https://www.habrador.com/tutorials/math/14-constrained-delaunay/) that can be used to create a simple navmesh from cutout geometry. However, this does not seem sufficient to generate a high quality navmesh from any arbitrary set of level geometry from scratch.

One of the problems is that it only deals with triangles in XZ space. But how should I handle situations where an arbitrary 3D mesh is intersecting another arbitrary 3D mesh? Within their intersection, each triangle would need to retriangulated in some way.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Recast](https://github.com/recastnavigation/recastnavigation)?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes I have I suppose I need to look into that a bit deeper but I find it hard to navigate the code

Comment: That gives a good sense of the complexity of a versatile solution that can handle arbitrary meshes and intersections like you describe. So, probably not something that we can fully explain in an answer here. You may want to edit your question to focus on just one step of the process, or one aspect of the Recast code you need help integrating or understanding. That would help narrow this question into an answerable scope.